# How to fill a draw line with mosaic in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-image

I wanna build an iOS app in swift to do something like a painting app, but I draw and create mosaic at the path where I moved my finger. I have two imageView `photoView` and `tempImageView`. PhotoView load the photo and tempImageView to draw. Here is some code

```
func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(photoView.frame.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        tempImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: photoView.frame.size.width, height: photoView.frame.size.height))

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toPoint.x, toPoint.y)

        CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushWidth)
        //next line will fill the line with black color but how to fill with mosaic?
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)

        CGContextStrokePath(context)

        tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
```

And I know next code can add a filter to a photo, but how to put it on a path or line?

```
var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate")
let inputImage = CIImage(image: originalImage)
filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this  -http://www.raywenderlich.com/87899/make-simple-drawing-app-uikit-swift

Comment: Yes, but something more than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw mask image in your draw code and composite pixelate image and original image with your mask. But for good performance you should use shared bitmap context.
If you create a CGImage from bitmap context, then the CGImage creates without copy data from the context. [CGBitmapContextCreateImage documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreateImage).
Later you can use [CIBlendWithAlphaMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBlendWithAlphaMask) or [CIBlendWithMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBlendWithMask) filter to get result image.

I think it is good method, but as result you will have cropped mosaic bits.